# Why is boron inert to acids and bases?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, boron-family

I was reading my school text book and in the segment related to the reactivity of group 13 elements with acids and alkalis it was written:
**Boron does not react with acids and alkalis even at moderate temperatures**
Earlier it said that it is weakly acidic so I attributed that to it's non reactivity with acids but I can't seem to find any reason why it doesn't react with bases.

Comment: I was more interested in the reason but thanks

Comment: That's not the way life works. Negative assertions don't require explanations; positive do. Why didn't Donald Trump climb Mount Everest? Er, well...

Comment: Ok ok i got your point XD, but i can't say that if a question is asked about it

Comment: Crystalline boron is quite similar to diamond. I doubt you'd ask the same about it?